# How to inject empty rows of list with ngrepeat, AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

my code is working, but I was wondering if there is a better way of injecting empty rows into a table (just for look and feel).
It seems a bit redundant, but cannot find the right example how to do it better.
my code for now:

```
<tr class="{{row.class}}" ng-repeat="row in someList | filter:{class:'special'}">
  <td>{{row.name}}</td>
</tr>
<!-- empty row -->
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="{{row.class}}" ng-repeat="row in someList | filter:{class:'other'}">
  <td>{{row.name}}</td>
</tr>
<!-- empty row -->
<tr>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="{{row.class}}" ng-repeat="row in someList | filter:{class:'final'}">
  <td>{{row.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Your approach is okay. You can't avoid it unless you create three separate tables.

Comment: Can use `groupBy` but requires repeating either a `tbody` or `table` as well

Comment: You should use a directive for this stuff

Comment: @MohanSingh `ng-repeat` is a directive ... so what would your suggested directive do that would be different?

Comment: Give me little time, i can create a directive for you.

Comment: @Mafti 
Did my answer solve your problem? Maybe we can further improve it towards a better solution...

Answer (score 2):

I got two different solutions for you:

### CSS combined with `orderBy`

You might might use a single `ng-repeat` to display all rows in the correct order with `orderBy:'class'`:

```
<table>
  <tr class="{{row.class}}" ng-repeat="row in someList | orderBy:!'class'">
    <td>{{row.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

With the help of CSS you may then add some visiual space between the three sections:

```
.other td,  .final td{
  padding-top:1em;
}

.other ~ .other td, .final ~ .final td{
  padding-top:0px;   
}
```

You can see the result in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gXPxgPWpDtbb7VbVF4yA?p=preview)

### Pure angularJS with `groupBy` of [angular.filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) module

For this solution you need to wrap each block into a `<tbody>` in order to use a nested `ng-repeat`. You might either style your `<tbody>` tags to leave some space inbetween or add an empty row as shown below. You can hide this row conditionally to get rid of the empty row at the end of the table.

```
<table>
  <tbody ng-repeat="(key, value) in someList | groupBy:'class'">
    {{key}}
    <tr class="{{key}}" ng-repeat="row in value">
      <td>{{row.name}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-if="key != 'final'"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is [the corresponding plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/xDTB1tUXdNhNfcscNpxu?p=preview).

Comment: you could probably also use `$last` from `ng-repeat` to check if it's the last entry